# Breezehome name shows up as "Äîì òåïëûõ âåòîâ"

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

For some reason, it says that the Breezehome name is "Äîì òåïëûõ âåòîâ". There's other places too that has gotten weird names like that. How do I fix this issue?

Comment: Did you change the language settings? Seems like a localization issue.

Comment: What mods do you have installed?

Answer (score 4):

It is in Russian ("Дом теплых ветов", actually should be "Дом тёплых ветров"). This is either encoding or font issue.

I suggest you reinstalling the game. Probably, you have applied a patch that was meant to be for the Russian version only.

Answer (score 0):

If it had all of a sudden happened a while after you had bought breeze home simply load a previous save to when it was called breeze home and then load it back to your current save, this should make the program realise that is what it is supposed to be, I hope this works